Trouble with fixing a Picture next left to the header
Reference: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume-anonymous/cstpnrbkhndn
I want to add a Picture on the left side of the header.

Please make your question self-sustained so it will still be useful for future users in case the link stops working.

You can add
\usepackage{graphicx}

to your preamble, and then use
\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image} \par
\vspace{\dimexpr-4\baselineskip-\parskip}

before the centered header is set; just replace example-image with the image of your choice. A different scale (or height) should be accompanied with a greater negative \vspace.

